# Treid integrations of 2 form tipes Submitting date

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently busy with an employee system and need help please. Over the last couple of days I have researched the web on forms and are now trying to build one solution out of two form types. New to php so please excuse if my terms are not correct.

The first form I am used was to simply display and allow for editing of data withing the database table. I need the user to be able to upload files to their employees so I got another form doing that part. Both worked 100% before combining the two.

I have placed all the php coding withing the same file used for the form. Reading through the code you should get the idea of what fields I have within my table. The added parts is the upload of warning forms. I need the three upload boxes to upload the files to the server and place a reference withing the row field.

Please assist and keep in mind that this is my first real php project when giving replies.

```
                <?php
include 'core/init.php';
protect_page();
include 'includes/overall/header.php';
error_reporting(1);
?>

<?php
/* 
 EDIT.PHP
 Allows user to edit specific entry in database
*/

 // creates the edit record form
 // since this form is used multiple times in this file, I have made it a function that is easily reusable
 function renderForm($idnumber, $firstname, $lastname, $department, $manager, $startdate, $warning1, $warning2, $warning3, $error)
 {
 ?>
 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
 <html>
 <head>
 <title>Edit Record</title>
 </head>
 <body>

<div class="article">

 <h1>Employee Details</h1>
 <div class="article">

 <?php 
 // if there are any errors, display them
 if ($error != '')
 {
 echo '<div style="padding:4px; border:1px solid red; color:red;">'.$error.'</div>';
 }
 ?> 
 <div class="article">
 <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input type="hidden" name="idnumber" value="<?php echo $idnumber; ?>"/>

 <div>
 <p>* Required</p>
 <p><strong>ID:</strong> <?php echo $idnumber; ?></p>
 <table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">
 <tr>
 <td><strong>First Name: *</strong></td>
 <td><input type="text" name="firstname" value="<?php echo $firstname; ?>"/></td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
 <td><strong>Last Name: *</strong></td>
 <td> <input type="text" name="lastname" value="<?php echo $lastname; ?>"/></td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
 <td><strong>Department: *</strong> </td>
 <td> <input type="text" name="department" value="<?php echo $department; ?>"/></td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
 <td><strong>Manager/Superviser:  *</strong></td>
 <td><input type="text" name="manager" value="<?php echo $manager; ?>"/></td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
 <td><strong>Start Date:  *</strong></td>
 <td><input type="text" name="startdate" value="<?php echo $startdate; ?>"/></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>
 <table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">

 <tr>
 <td><label for="file">Select a file:</label> <input type="file" name="warning1" id="file"> <br />
      </td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
 <td><label for="file">Select a file:</label> <input type="file" name="warning2" id="file"> <br />
      </td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
 <td><label for="file">Select a file:</label> <input type="file" name="warning3" id="file"> <br />
      </td>
 </tr>


 </table>
 </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="btn"></td>
 </tr>
 </table>

 </div>
 </form> 

 </body>
 </html> 

 <?php
 }




 // check if the form has been submitted. If it has, process the form and save it to the database
 if (isset($_POST['submit']))
 { 
 // confirm that the 'id' value is a valid integer before getting the form data
 if (is_numeric($_POST['idnumber']))
 {
 // get form data, making sure it is valid
 $idnumber = $_POST['idnumber'];
 $firstname = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['firstname']));
 $lastname = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['lastname']));
  $department = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['department']));
   $manager = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['manager']));
    $startdate = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['startdate']));
 $warning1 = $_FILES['warning1']['name'];
   $warning2 = $_FILES['warning2']['name'];
   $warning3 = $_FILES['warning3']['name'];
 // check that firstname/lastname fields are both filled in
 if ($firstname == '' || $lastname == '')

 {
 // generate error message
 $error = 'ERROR: Please fill in all fields!';

 //error, display form
 renderForm($idnumber, $firstname, $lastname, $department, $manager, $startdate, $error);
 }
 else
 {
 // save the data to the database
 mysql_query("UPDATE ref_employees SET firstname='$firstname', lastname='$lastname', department='$department', manager='$manager',  startdate='$startdate', warning1='$warning1', warning2='$warning2', warning3='$warning3' WHERE idnumber='$idnumber'")
 or die(mysql_error()); 

 // once saved, redirect back to the view page
 header("Location: employeelist.php"); 
 }
 }
 else
 {
 // if the 'id' isn't valid, display an error
 echo 'Error!';
 }
 }
 else

 // if the form hasn't been submitted, get the data from the db and display the form
 {

 // get the 'id' value from the URL (if it exists), making sure that it is valid (checing that it is numeric/larger than 0)
 if (isset($_GET['idnumber']) && is_numeric($_GET['idnumber']) && $_GET['idnumber'] > 0)
 {
 // query db
 $idnumber = $_GET['idnumber'];
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ref_employees WHERE idnumber=$idnumber")
 or die(mysql_error()); 
 $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

 // check that the 'id' matches up with a row in the databse
 if($row)
 {

 // get data from db
 $firstname = $row['firstname'];
 $lastname = $row['lastname'];
 $department = $row['department'];
 $manager = $row['manager'];
 $startdate = $row['startdate'];

 // show form
 renderForm($idnumber, $firstname, $lastname, $department, $manager, $startdate, '');
 }
 else
 // if no match, display result
 {
 echo "No results!";
 }
 }
 else
 // if the 'id' in the URL isn't valid, or if there is no 'id' value, display an error
 {
 echo 'Error!';
 }
 }
?>
 <?php
   // Configuration - Your Options
      $allowed_filetypes = array('.pdf'); // These will be the types of file that will pass the validation.
      $max_filesize = 524288; // Maximum filesize in BYTES (currently 0.5MB).
      $upload_path = 'files/empdocs'; // The place the files will be uploaded to (currently a 'files' directory).

   $warning1 = $_FILES['warning1']['name'];
   $warning2 = $_FILES['warning2']['name'];
   $warning3 = $_FILES['warning3']['name']; // Get the name of the file (including file extension).
   $ext1 = substr($warning1, strpos($warning1,'.'), strlen($warning1)-1); 
   $ext2 = substr($warning2, strpos($warning2,'.'), strlen($warning1)-1); 
   $ext3 = substr($warning3, strpos($warning3,'.'), strlen($warning1)-1); // Get the extension from the filename.

   // Check if the filetype is allowed, if not DIE and inform the user.
   if(!in_array($ext,$allowed_filetypes))
      die('The file you attempted to upload is not allowed.');

   // Now check the filesize, if it is too large then DIE and inform the user.
   if(filesize($_FILES['warning1']['tmp_name']) > $max_filesize)
      die('The file you attempted to upload is too large.');
     else if(filesize($_FILES['warning2']['tmp_name']) > $max_filesize)
      die('The file you attempted to upload is too large.');
     else if(filesize($_FILES['warning3']['tmp_name']) > $max_filesize)
      die('The file you attempted to upload is too large.');

   // Check if we can upload to the specified path, if not DIE and inform the user.
   if(!is_writable($upload_path))
      die('You cannot upload to the specified directory, please CHMOD it to 777.');

   // Upload the file to your specified path.
   if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['warning1']['tmp_name'],$upload_path . $filename)
   && move_uploaded_file($_FILES['warning2']['tmp_name'],$upload_path . $filename)
   && move_uploaded_file($_FILES['warning3']['tmp_name'],$upload_path . $filename))
         echo 'Your file upload was successful, view the file <a href="' . $upload_path . $filename . '" title="Your File">here</a>'; // It worked.
   else
         echo 'There was an error during the file upload.  Please try again.'; // It failed :(.

?>
</div>

</form>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loose the `,` before `WHERE` in

```
mysql_query("UPDATE ref_employees SET firstname='$firstname', lastname='$lastname', department='$department', manager='$manager',  startdate='$startdate', wirning1='$warning1', warning2='$warning2', warning3='$warning3', WHERE idnumber='$idnumber'")
```

---

Also, you are using the same variable (`$ext`) in these three lines:

```
   $ext = substr($warning1, strpos($warning1,'.'), strlen($warning1)-1); 
   $ext = substr($warning2, strpos($warning2,'.'), strlen($warning1)-1); 
   $ext = substr($warning3, strpos($warning3,'.'), strlen($warning1)-1); // Get the
```

extension from the filename.

...which make the first two pointless. Try using `$ext1=`, `$ext2=`, `$ext3=` *(update the rest of your code accordingly)*.

---

Also, in the above `UPDATE`, you are using uninitialized `$warning{x}` variables.

Comment: The selected files do not upload. to the file directory specified. I need a reference to be placed within my database in the relating fields i.e. when I choose to upload warning files for employee x then withing the databse I sould like the filename or any trackable reference to placed within the fields named "warning1" & "warning2" & "warning3"

I also have the following line displaying underneath my submit button 
"The file you attempted to upload is not allowed."

Please Advise! Thank you

Comment: Where should I then place the "$warning{x} variables"

Comment: Apparently, you should give them values _before_ they are used (ie before the `UPDATE` needs to execute).

Comment: Thank you. it is now showing the full filename that was uploaded. I have edited my code above... Now the files are not showing up on the server. I have made sure that my directory permissions is set to 777?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38827/discussion-between-maurice-botha-and-geomagas)

Comment: Well, _apparently_ the problem is at `move_uploaded_file`. Look, I can't debug the whole application. I already solved more that your original problem. Give it some effort, otherwise you won't learn.